# Get page driver from inside SitePrism page

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist, site-prism

How can I get page driver from inside the SitePrism page?

According to [poltergeist docs](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) all I need is to call:

```
page.driver
```

But it refers to the Capybara page, not SitePrism's page. The question therefore: how to get Capybara page when you are using SitePrism? I wasn't able to find `page`/`driver` method or something like that in SitePrism.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by looking at capybara and siteprism sources. All you need is to call the `page` method:

```
page.page.driver
```

Comment: If you could add the github link (from site_prism) where you found it? Thanks.